# How to link logged in webpages to Excel

Tags: excel, vba

How do I link data from a user specific webpage, i.e one you need to be logged in on (for example Instagram followers or Facebook friends) etc to a spreadsheet?

From what I can see, the Data -> From Web option only lets you do it from open webpages, i.e those that you don't need to log in and is not specific to the user.

Is there a way I can do this on Excel?

Comment: While you have been around for a while, I would still like to remind you that StackOverflow is not a free code-writing service. Yet, we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) with their code. So, if you don't have a specific coding question then you are probably posting this question on the wrong site. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more information which posts are on-topic.

Comment: @durbnpoisn Well this project was supposed to be my way of learning. Maybe I should not ever learn anything I don't know as I don't know it?

Comment: @Ralph Am I not asking a specific question in how to link user specific, logged in webpages to my spreadsheet?

Comment: @Kaish...  That is not at all what I am suggesting.  What I AM suggesting is that you start smaller.  Give yourself something a little less ambitious.  Because learning programming concepts and new languages is not something to be taken lightly.  It takes YEARS.  I've been doing various programming for 30 years, in at least as many languages, and I'm still learning stuff all the time.  So don't take my comment as an insult.  Consider it a push in the right direction.

Comment: The following link might be able to help you find a starting point for your question(s): http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367

Comment: @durbnpoisn Ah I see. Sorry about that! I know BASIC programming (some unix, awk, LUA and other languages like HTML and CSS and some basic Matlab) but I think I just wanted a shortcut to more interesting programming (like Java) and thought the best way to do it was via a project I found interesting, as the best way I found to learn those other things was by doing something rather than working through a text book etc

Comment: @Ralph Ok thanks for that, I see what I have done. I will try to revise the question, edit and re-post it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be enough to get you started.

```
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim oBrowser As InternetExplorer
Sub Login_2_Website()

Dim oHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim sURL As String

On Error GoTo Err_Clear
sURL = "https://www.google.com/accounts/Login"
Set oBrowser = New InternetExplorer
oBrowser.Silent = True
oBrowser.timeout = 60
oBrowser.navigate sURL
oBrowser.Visible = True

Do
' Wait till the Browser is loaded
Loop Until oBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set HTMLDoc = oBrowser.Document

HTMLDoc.all.Email.Value = "sample@vbadud.com"
HTMLDoc.all.passwd.Value = "*****"

For Each oHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
If oHTML_Element.Type = "submit" Then oHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
Next

' oBrowser.Refresh ' Refresh If Needed
Err_Clear:
If Err <> 0 Then
Debug.Assert Err = 0
Err.Clear
Resume Next
End If
End Sub
```

http://vbadud.blogspot.com/2009/08/how-to-login-to-website-using-vba.html